# why the file command in a for loop behaves so ridiculous

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, echo

```
#!/bin/sh

file_list=`find . -type f`

IFS=$(echo) #this enables for loop to break on newline
for file_ in $file_list; do
  file $file_
done
```

This shell script will amazingly report that `(File name too long)`. I guess that the script feeds `file` with 3 times `$file_list` !!!

But if I change the `file` command with a simple `echo`, then the script will print all files in the current directory line by line which is expected.

Comment: You are setting `IFS` to null and disabling word splitting. So `file_` contains the *entire* output of `find`. That's going to be a bit too long for the command line to work. `echo` is "working" because the newlines make it through to display. Try using `printf %s "$file_"` or `declare -p file_` in the loop and see what you get.

Comment: Also see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to properly read line-by-line data from a stream. And read [Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) to see why that's a bad idea.

Comment: You probably meant to use `IFS=$(echo)` (command substitution, not a parameter expansion). But it's still a bad idea.

Comment: Even `IFS=$(echo)` won't work because command substitution strips trailing newlines, so IFS is still empty

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to iterate over the results of `find`. Use it's `exec` option instead:

```
find -type f -exec file {} \;
```